# mysql query to check greater than date and time

Tags: php, mysql

I have two date and time columns in my database. I want to get rows where date is greater than or equal to current date and current time

I have used below query to get result

```
SELECT DISTINCT     
A.appt_fromUser,A.date,A.time,A.appt_styleType,B.*,A.appt_shoutID,A.shout_status 
from appoint_db A 
INNER JOIN checkedin_db B ON A.appt_id=B.appid 
where A.appt_toUser='$userid' 
and A.date>='$date' 
and InChair='0' 
and A.time>='$time'
```

However this isn't working as I'd hoped.

Eg, if I have two rows:

2012/05/30 Time:6.00
2012/05/30 Time:13.00

And I query this with date of 2012/05/02 and Time:12:00, it returns only only the row where the time is greater than 12:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only check the time if the date is the same as the one you're checking against.

```
SELECT DISTINCT     
A.appt_fromUser,A.date,A.time,A.appt_styleType,B.*,A.appt_shoutID,A.shout_status
from appoint_db A
INNER JOIN checkedin_db B ON A.appt_id=B.appid 
where A.appt_toUser='$userid'
and   InChair='0'
and (
       A.date>'$date'
       OR (
           A.date = '$date'
           AND
           A.time>='$time'
       )
    )
```

You could also concatenate the date and time before selecting. I wouldn't though (might not work with some locales).

```
SELECT DISTINCT
A.appt_fromUser,A.date,A.time,A.appt_styleType,B.*,A.appt_shoutID,A.shout_status
from appoint_db A
INNER JOIN checkedin_db B ON A.appt_id=B.appid
where A.appt_toUser=1
and InChair='0'
AND CONCAT(A.date, ' ', A.time) >= '$date $time'
```

Answer (score 0):

The now() function in mysql returs current timestamp . you can use that